# FadeAnimation code errors while trying to update simple_animations: ^2.2.1 after migration using sa_v1_migration: ^1.1.2

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create a Fade animation and it is working it gives problems and says that it's deprecated and I need to migrate:

I get the following three problems:

1. 'MultiTrackTween' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. See migration guide: https://pub.dev/packages/sa_v1_migration.
   Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
2. 'Track' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. See migration guide: https://pub.dev/packages/sa_v1_migration.
   Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
3. 'Track' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. See migration guide: https://pub.dev/packages/sa_v1_migration.
   Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.

following is the code for my FadeAnimation.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';


class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child, {AssetImage image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity").add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateY").add(
        Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
        curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    return PlayAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]), 
          child: child
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: MyApp
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  simple_animations: ^2.2.1
  sa_v1_migration: ^1.1.2
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:




  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.

  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  assets:
   - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:


  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I'm unable to upgrade the code in a manner that I get the desire results. Can someone please help me update this code so I don't get the deprecated errors.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can define an `enum AniProps` and use `MultiTween<AniProps>`

code snippet

```
enum AniProps { opacity, translateY }

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child, {AssetImage image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<AniProps>()
      ..add(AniProps.opacity, 0.0.tweenTo(1.0), 500.milliseconds)
      ..add(AniProps.translateY, (-30.0).tweenTo(0.0), 500.milliseconds,
          Curves.easeOut);


    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AniProps>>(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
        opacity: value.get(AniProps.opacity),
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, value.get(AniProps.translateY)), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}

...
FadeAnimation(
            10.0,
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.blue,
            )),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';
import 'package:supercharged/supercharged.dart';

enum AniProps { opacity, translateY }

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child, {AssetImage image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<AniProps>()
      ..add(AniProps.opacity, 0.0.tweenTo(1.0), 500.milliseconds)
      ..add(AniProps.translateY, (-30.0).tweenTo(0.0), 500.milliseconds,
          Curves.easeOut);
    /*
    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity").add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateY").add(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);*/

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AniProps>>(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
        opacity: value.get(AniProps.opacity),
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, value.get(AniProps.translateY)), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FadeAnimation(
                10.0,
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect; thanks @chunhunghan .... your help is much appreciated..

Comment: @chunhunghan I tried this solution but I have an error whit the tweenTo, it says `The method 'tweenTo' isn't defined for the type 'double'.` and I followed the official documentation but the error keeps popping up.

Comment: @victcdva, you need to import supercharged, you can see line 3 of full code.

Comment: Use like this: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0), const Duration(milliseconds: 500)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code its gonna work I made changes to remove those deprecated usage

```
enum AnimationType { opacity, translateX }

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  const FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<AnimationType>()
      ..add(AnimationType.opacity, Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
          Duration(milliseconds: 500),)
      ..add(
        AnimationType.translateX,
        Tween(begin: 30.0, end: 1.0),
        Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      );

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AnimationType>>(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
        opacity: value.get(AnimationType.opacity),
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(value.get(AnimationType.translateX), 0), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you update to v5 you can use the code

```
class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MovieTween()
      ..tween('opacity', Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeIn)
      ..tween(
          'translateY',
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut);

    return CustomAnimationBuilder(
        delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
        duration: tween.duration,
        tween: tween,
        child: child,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Movie value, Widget? child) {
          return Opacity(
              opacity: value.get("opacity"),
              child: Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(0.0, value.get("translateY")), child: child
                  )
              );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is solution**

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';

enum AniProps { opacity, translateY }

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(
    this.delay,
    this.child,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTween<AniProps>(
        // [
        //  Track("opacity").add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
        //   Track("translateY").add(
        //     Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
        //     curve: Curves.easeOut)
        // ]

        )
      ..add(
        AniProps.opacity,
        Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
        const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      )
      ..add(AniProps.translateY, Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
          const Duration(milliseconds: 500), Curves.easeOut);

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AniProps>>(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
        opacity: value.get(AniProps.opacity), //(animation as Map)["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, value.get(AniProps.translateY)), child: child),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final tween = new MultiTrackTween([
      
    new Track <dynamic>("opacity")
          .add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      
      
    Track("translateY").add(
          Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -100.0, end: 0.0),
          curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    
    return ControlledAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builderWithChild: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```